installer must be run from source monter .dmg
(The installer must be run from source monter .dmg)
I'm facing this problem while installing few softwares.
v: sequoia 15.1
any help?
I tried to force the installation from the terminal but it didn't work.
I also changed my security installation source to anywhere.
